# my changes did not got pushed to my master repository

Tags: git, git-bash

I have a repository 
which I could push from my local machine when I created for the first time.
by doing `git push -u origin master`
I keep making changes in the files and 
now I did

```
$ git commit -m "bibliography changes in .bib file"
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
        modified:   BIBeusflat2019.bib
        modified:   EUSFLAT2019_template.aux
        modified:   EUSFLAT2019_template.bbl
        modified:   EUSFLAT2019_template.blg
        modified:   EUSFLAT2019_template.log
        modified:   EUSFLAT2019_template.pdf
        modified:   EUSFLAT2019_template.synctex.gz
        modified:   EUSFLAT2019_template.tex

no changes added to commit
```

then I did

```
$ git push -u origin master
Everything up-to-date
Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'origin'.
```

now I checked from the web interface. I was surprised no changes were pushed I mean the file         `modified:   EUSFLAT2019_template.bbl`
is the file in which I did changes so I expected the bibliography entries in this to change.
But it was as if I had pushed it first time no changes.

Then I tried

```
$ git add -A
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in BIBeusflat2019.bib.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in EUSFLAT2019_template.aux.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in EUSFLAT2019_template.log.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in EUSFLAT2019_template.tex.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
```

and then

```
$ git push -u origin master
Everything up-to-date
Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'origin'.
```

but then also there was no change on the file which I accessed via web interface.
So now what should I do? Am I doing some mistake here?

*update1*
as mentioned in comments here is

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   BIBeusflat2019.bib
        modified:   EUSFLAT2019_template.aux
        modified:   EUSFLAT2019_template.bbl
        modified:   EUSFLAT2019_template.blg
        modified:   EUSFLAT2019_template.log
        modified:   EUSFLAT2019_template.pdf
        modified:   EUSFLAT2019_template.synctex.gz
        modified:   EUSFLAT2019_template.tex
```

now I check

```
$ git log
commit 04a1e28b5e47b35275c15e72886a22885eec9b1d (HEAD -> master, origin/master)
Author: asaad
Date:   Sun Mar 29 02:31:16 2020 +0530

    29-3-2020

commit eff88becc48786dc379cf138199bd04314052533
Author: asadd
Date:   Sun Mar 29 02:29:42 2020 +0530

    first commit
```

*update2*
as per the answer I changed the README.md of the project just to make sure what is asked in answer is met so now I again do

```
$ git add -A
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in README.md.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
```

then I did

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   BIBeusflat2019.bib
        modified:   EUSFLAT2019_template.aux
        modified:   EUSFLAT2019_template.bbl
        modified:   EUSFLAT2019_template.blg
        modified:   EUSFLAT2019_template.log
        modified:   EUSFLAT2019_template.pdf
        modified:   EUSFLAT2019_template.synctex.gz
        modified:   EUSFLAT2019_template.tex
        modified:   README.md
```

then

```
$ git commit -m "third change Readme.md"
[master acdc9be] third change Readme.md
 9 files changed, 243 insertions(+), 247 deletions(-)
 rewrite EUSFLAT2019_template.synctex.gz (84%)
```

now I did again

```
$ $ git status
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
bash: $: command not found
```

now again I did

```
$ git push -u origin master
Enumerating objects: 21, done.
Counting objects: 100% (21/21), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (11/11), done.
Writing objects: 100% (11/11), 130.34 KiB | 4.83 MiB/s, done.
Total 11 (delta 8), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (8/8), completed with 8 local objects.
To https://github.com/kiotie32/firstpaper.git
   04a1e28..acdc9be  master -> master
Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'origin'.
```

now I did

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Comment: Use `git status` to show the state of your working directory; are there any modified files?  Also you can use `git log` to check that the head of your current branch has been pushed to `origin/master`.  You should expect to see output of the following form: `commit ed2b76e89c1982e82e00d5167c13f4e770a139e3 (HEAD -> master, origin/master)` when you run `git log`.

Comment: I updated the information in question, you mentioned in commands git status ,git log but I do not know what it means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've tried to commit the files before having staged (added) them.  You need to stage your changes first, then commit them and finally push this commit to the remote.  To fix:

1. `git add -A` to stage all of these modifications.  If at this point you do a `git status` then beneath the text `Changes to be committed:` you should see your files listed.
2. `git commit -m "Your commit message goes here"` to commit these changes (substituting a sensible commit message ofc). This will commit these changes in your local repository.  If you do a `git status` at this point you should see output saying `nothing to commit, working tree clean`.
3. `git push` to push your changes to the remote.

Comment: this much I know I mean meaning of git add ,git commit,git push even after doing all this the changes did not got pushed.

Comment: Do a `git status` after each stage and add the output to your question.

Comment: the git status output I mentioned above is today after doing changes when I decided to post the question and after your comment I did git status.

Comment: The output of your `git status` shows that you haven't committed your changes, you need to do a `git commit -m "Your commit message goes here"`.

Comment: surprise to know this because the first code block in my question has `git commit -m "bibliography changes in .bib file"` that was after doing all changes in my local machine.

Comment: yes you pointed correctly I did `git commit` before `git add -A` I did all the things again from start it worked. I want to know from online git version if I want to switch back to project at previous stage is it possible by some git command like git clone previous state before commit or ,state of repository on a previous date. As of now I do it manually I make a copy of folder before making changes and then after many days I when mess with some thing then I look in that backup folder what were things before?